# Rendered Image is not same shape and missing area

Tags: rendering

[image]

Hello, I am just beginning with 3d printing/rendering for my work. I've been trying to understand the nuances of the programs I am using but I'm starting to hit blocks. I've tried looking up and understanding what is happening but with no luck. The picture attached shows what I'm working with. The far left is from Blender, my object. The middle is after I save the rendered image and import into QIDI slicer software. The far right shows the chunk missing from the top of the object.

Why is this happening to my image?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? The first image doesn't really show anything apart from a scaled cube. Share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page and upload an image of your complete blender window (Window > Save Screenshot iin Blender.)

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/7AYmvezp

Comment: You are correct, the object is just a scaled cube. I'm looking to make a 'bolt board'. I've printed the bolts/nuts, now I just need a large rectangle that I'm going to drill and thread the holes.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is that you apply the scale to it before you export it from Blender which you can do in Object mode by selecting the cube and then using Ctrl-A > Scale. Apart from that there's nothing in Blender which could be creating the missing chunk so I suggest you investigate problems elsewhere.